# isset() or empty() statements not giving desired results

Tags: php

I am using the following code which is giving the same result irrespective of the condition;

```
foreach($data as $row) 
{
    $a = $row['name']; //Here I am calling name from an api
    if(empty($a)) 
    {
        $a = 'AAA'; // Checking if a$ = $row['']; i.e. 'name' does not exist
    }
    echo $a;
}
```

The problem is when `$row['name']` has value, it is getting echoed via `$a`, but if `$row['name']` does not exist, I am getting error as undefined index: (probably for since 'name' is not available for that row.)

How to get `$a` echoed as `'AAA'` in case `$row['name']` does not exist?

Answer (score 1):

Try checking the actual array and not the declaration of the null.

```
if(!isset($row['name']))
    $a = "AAAA";
```

https://ideone.com/RuqOBs

The difference is subtle but important :

`isset` — Determine if a variable **is set and is not** NULL

`empty` — Determine whether a variable is empty

`is_null` — Finds whether a variable is NULL

Answer (score 1):

write the `else` part  like this :

```
foreach($data as $row){

    if(empty($row['name']) || ! isset($row['name']) )
    {
      $a = 'AAA';} 
    }
    else
    {
      $a = $row['name'];
    }
 echo $a;
}
```

`isset()` checks if a variable has a value including ( False , 0 , or empty string) , but not NULL. Returns `TRUE` if var exists; `FALSE` otherwise.

On the other hand the `empty()` function checks if the variable has an empty value empty string , 0, NULL ,or False. Returns `FALSE` if var has a non-empty and non-zero value.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if name is set before doing your test and combine then into a single statement.

```
$a = (isset($row['name']) ? $row['name'] : 'AAA');
echo $a;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are three functions to choose from, which have the following differences:

- [`array_key_exists($key, $array)`](http://php.net/array_key_exists)

  This will check if the key exists in the array. If it does, no matter what value is stored behind it (even `null`), it will return `true`, `false` oterhwise.
- [`isset($array[$key])`](http://php.net/isset)

  This will check if the key in the array exists and if the value behind it is not `null`. If it exists and is not `null` it will return `true`, `false` oterhwise.
- [`empty($array[$key])`](http://php.net/empty)

  This will check if the key exists and if the value behind it is [falsy](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php). If it does not exist or the value is [falsy](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php) (For example `null`, `false`, `''` or `0`) it will return `true`, `false` otherwise.

---

All those functions have in common, that you call them on the array directly. For you, you could call it like this:

```
foreach($data as $row) {
    echo array_key_exists('name', $row) ? $row['name'] : 'AAA';
}
```

You can exchange `array_key_exists('name', $row)` with any of the other two functions, depending of what kind of behavior you want.